# Replacing a design to use capturing lambda only

Tags: c++, lambda

I am trying to generalize a callback mechanism.

I need two things for that:

Calling it in a general matter:  `void call()` - that I was able to manage

I mean that everyone can get a `void call()` function, and I can even (easily) store them in an array. They are all of the same type.

```
class Function{
    public:
    virtual void call()=0;
};

template<typename T>
class TemplatedFunction : public Function{
    public:
    int (T::*m_fkt)();
    T* m_obj;
 
    TemplatedFunction(T* obj, int (T::*fkt)()):m_fkt(fkt),m_obj(obj){}

   // Can also set here a [&](){ f(Args...args) } that will capture the callback arguments, and call it via call(). f being the std::function created for the callback.

    void call(){
      (m_obj->*m_fkt)();
    }
};
```

Set (register callback) in a general matter: here I got lost...

My callbacks are statically allocated.

I saw this great option, but my only option is using a capturing lambda.
( no `bind`, or `tuple`.. )

This option is great as I can store an array of `EventHandler` that basically will differ by the ID of a message I will get. Unfortunately I can't use `new`. (I use an in place static allocation for lambda)

```
class EventHandler{
public:
Function* m_func=nullptr;

template<class T> 
void SetCallbackFunction(T* obj, void (T::*mem_fkt)()){
    if(m_func != nullptr)
        delete m_func;
    m_func = new TemplatedFunction<T>(obj,mem_fkt); // can't use it.
}

void TestCallback(){
    if(m_func != nullptr)
        m_func->call();
}

~EventHandler(){
    if(m_func != nullptr)
        delete m_func;
}
```

};

As of my callbacks are statically allocated in advanced, containing the option to call, but not to set.

I know that there are many designs available, but I am limited to using a capturing lambda only with an `std::function` replacement to store it.

My goal is to pass a single type EventHandler to all my messages, without the need to template the messages, so I will be able to store them in a `std::array<Msg_t>`

here how I want it to look in the end:

```
// Statically allocated callbacks that have general `void call()`
//Function* m_func_to_run_callback1 = TemplatedFunction<> Callback1();
// Function* m_func_to_run_callback2 = TemplatedFunction<> Callback2();

int main() 
{
    EventHandler eh, eh1;
    Foo foo; // some class
    Foo2 foo2; // some other class
    eh.SetCallbackFunction(&foo, &Foo::bar, m_func_to_run_callback1 ) ;
    eh1.SetCallbackFunction(&foo2, &Foo2::bar2, m_func_to_run_callback1) ;
    return 0;
}
```

I think that what I am missing is :

```
class Function{
public:
virtual void call()=0;
virtual void set(void*) = 0; // void* being the callback function

};
```

Comment: Seems like you just need to change `m_func` to `std:: function`?

Comment: I don't want to template the EventHandler for type

Comment: Why would you need to use a template? Can't you just use `std::function<void()>`

Comment: Capturing lambdas and std::function allocate memory on the heap (not every time but you cannot control it).

Comment: _Unfortunately I can't use `new`_ Why is that please? (I'm assuming you cannot use it by implication either).  That's going to severely cramp your style.

Comment: I can statically in place allocate a lambda (and capture)

Comment: Really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. It eventually looks like a std::bind to me, but you did not explained why this was not possible to be used....

Comment: I don't see it, how can the 'bind' replace the 'new'? Can 'bind' be replaced by capturing lambda ( I do have an option of capturing a lambda statically ) ?